# Access 2010 Afterupdate - set date on field

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I've got a DB that I need some help on please.

I've got a tasks database - I want to set a Date Completed when a status combo box is marked as Completed.

So my combobox is called "txtStatus"

I'd like for when that is set to Completed it updates a field in the Tasks table (called CompletedDate) to be populated with the current date.

I've tried doing an AfterUpdate and an If statement but I'm getting nowhere. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your Combo Box bound to a field in the [Tasks] table? If so, what is the field name?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you have sorted this, but just in case anyone else is struggling:

```
Private Sub txtStatus_AfterUpdate()
If Me.txtStatus = True Then
Me.CompletedDate = Date
Else
Me.CompletedDate = Null
End If
End Sub
```